# How can I replace the random values in a column in Studio with a sequential number set?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table of member data in my SQL database, and each member has a random but unique 8 digit number for their ID.

I want to be able to replace all those numbers with a sequential number starting from 1000, so it would replace:

```
24587469
22546587
14125638
98567458
```

With:

```
1001
1002
1003
1004
```

Etc.

My knowledge of SQL is very limited, and I haven't been able to find a method to do this that seems to work on google or here.

Comment: What is the logic behind your expected order?

Comment: Previously each member had an RFID tag, encoded with that 8 digit random-ish number. The RFID tags were phased out, and are now replaced with magnetic encoded swipe cards, which have each been encoded from 1001 to 8650, sequentially. It's irrelevant which member receives which number in that sequence, their name will be printed on the card after the encoded card is assigned to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about the order, then you may use `ROW_NUMBER` ordered by the data column:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT data, 1000 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY data) rn
    FROM yourTable
)
```

If you also want to update then use:

```
UPDATE cte
SET data = rn;
```

Comment: if you don't care then `order by (select null)`

Comment: I suggest that you should use `DENSE_RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()` to manage same numbers

Comment: @AlexSham `each member has a random but unique 8 digit number for their ID` ... I don't agree with your suggestion.

Comment: This has worked perfectly to get me the result I was after, thanks heaps!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, OP did mention it, yes, but dense_rank provides more common decision (for this case with unique members and similar cases with non-unique members).

Answer (score 1):

You can do using CTE:

```
DECLARE @YourTable TABLE 
(
    DealerId INT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @YourTable
(
    DealerId
)
VALUES
  (24587469)
, (22546587)
, (14125638)
, (98567458)

;with cte as (
    Select *
          , NewVal = 1000 + dense_rank() over ( order by DealerId)
     From  @YourTable
    )
UPDATE cte SET 
cte.DealerId = cte.NewVal
SELECT * FROM @YourTable 
ORDER BY DealerId
```

Output:

```
DealerId
1001
1002
1003
1004
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yeah, but I just wanted to show that it is possible to use another function. Is it ok?